# Generate set of points/coordinates to draw smooth parabola (semi-circle) given only a height, and a width

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a patient monitor simulator in JavaScript. This involves drawing parabolas (semi-circles) on an HTML canvas. Normally this wouldn't be an issue with the bezierCurveTo() function however this solution is not applicable here as I need to animate the curve pixel by pixel as demonstrated here http://www.jet5.com/ecg/. From my understanding this will require an array of all points in the curve.

My question is how can I generate this array of points from a provided width and height that I want the curve to be. Is there some sort of special command or algorithm that I can use to obtain these Cartesian coordinates. For a clearer picture of what I need please refer to the following image http://en.ecgpedia.org/wiki/File:Epi_endo_en.png.

A lecturer helped me with the following equation: y = (x - t1) x (t2 - x). Here is my code (I ave created a point object and remember this is for an HTML canvas where 0, 0 is in the top left corner):

```
var y = 0;
var duration = 200;
var t1 = 0;
var t2 = duration;
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
    x1 = i;
    x2 = duration - i;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    y = (x1 - t1) * (t2 - x2)

    if (i < duration / 2) {
       y = -y;
    }

    data.push(new point(y)); 
}
```

While this partly worked from my understanding this equation wouldn't allow me to specify a height only the parabolas width.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Naively i would say that the monitoring should just display the values that come, as they come, no ?

Comment: Do you mean from some sort of sensor? if so no. This is a simulator therefore the heights and widths of the traces have to be manually set

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do in this kind of mathematical situation is to **normalize**.
Which means here, try to always go back to the case when x is between 0 and 1.

so if x is in  [ t1 ; t2 ]

```
 delta = (x-t1) / (t2 - t1).
```

now delta moves in [0;1] !!! Magic

In the same way, for your shape functions use normalized function that returns only in  [ 0 ; 1].

The example you give in your code becomes :

```
 function shape(x) { return (x<0.5) ? x*(1-x) : -x*(1-x) }
```

And the code becomes - just to be clear -

```
for ( x = t1; x<t2; x++ ) {
    var delta = (x-t1) / (t2 - t1) ;
    y = amplitude * shape(delta);
   // do something with (x,y)
}
```

See a working jsbin here :

http://jsbin.com/wodecowibexa/1/edit?js,output

[image]

```
![var cv = document.getElementById('cv');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = '#C66';

// shift for all the drawings
var plotShift = {x:0, y:200 } ;

// draw between t1 and t2 with an initial y shift.
//  expects an easing function i.e. a function \[0;1\] -> \[0;1\]
//  yShift should be the last computed value.
//  returns the last computed value to allow chaining.
function drawEasingFunction (yShift, t1, t2, amplitude, func) {
   var x=0, y=0;
   var duration = t2 - t1;  
   for (x= t1; x < t2; x++) {
     // delta is a figure between 0 and 1
     var delta = (x - t1) / duration;
     //
     y = yShift + amplitude*func(delta);
     ctx.fillRect(x+plotShift.x,y+plotShift.y,2,2);
  }  
  return y;
}

var easingFunctions = \[
  function (x) { return x} , /*  line */
  function (x) { return x*x} , /*  line */
  function (x) { return Math.sqrt(x)} , /*  line */  
  function (x) { return Math.sin(Math.PI*x/2)} , /*  sin */
  function (x) { return x*(1-x)} , /*  that's your function */
\];

var lastY = 0;
var currentX = 0;
 var length = 50;

  // demo of all functions
  for (; currentX < cv.width; currentX+=length) {
  // take a random function
  var fnIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*easingFunctions.length) ;
  var thisEasingFunction = easingFunctions\[fnIndex\];
  // take some random amplitude
  var amplitude = (60 + Math.random()*10);
  // randomly switch the amplitude sign.
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) amplitude = -amplitude;
  // draw !  (and store last value)
  lastY = drawEasingFunction(lastY, currentX, currentX+length, amplitude, thisEasingFunction);  
  }][2]
```

Comment: Thankyou very much i'll take a look at your suggestion